# Not getting 0 index from pandas value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, count, dataframe, series

```
total_val_count = dataset[attr].value_counts()      
    for i in range(len(total_val_count.index)):
        print total_val_count[i]
```

I have written this piece of code which counts occurrences of all distinct values of an attribute in a dataframe. The problem I am facing is that I am unable to access the first value by using index 0. I get a KeyError: 0 error in the first  loop run itself.

The total_val_count contains proper values as shown below:

34    2887
4     2708
13    2523
35    2507
33    2407
3     2404
36    2382
26    2378
16    2282
22    2187
21    2141
12    2104
25    2073
5     2052
15    2044
17    2040
14    2027
28    1984
27    1980
23    1979
24    1960
30    1953
29    1936
31    1884
18    1877
7     1858
37    1767
20    1762
11    1740
8     1722
6     1693
32    1692
10    1662
9     1576
19    1308
2     1266
1      175
38      63
dtype: int64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`total_val_count` is a Series. The index of the Series are values in `dataset[attr]`, 
and the values in the Series are the number of times the associated value in `dataset[attr]` appears.

When you index a Series with `total_val_count[i]`, Pandas looks for `i` in the index and returns the assocated value. In other words, `total_val_count[i]` is indexing by index value, not by ordinal.
Think of a Series as a mapping from the index to the values. When using plain indexing, e.g. `total_val_count[i]`, it behaves more like a `dict` than a `list`.

You are getting a KeyError because `0` is not a value in the index.
To index by ordinal, use `total_val_count.iloc[i]`.

Having said that, using `for i in range(len(total_val_count.index))` -- or, what amounts to the same thing, `for i in range(len(total_val_count))` --  is not recommended.  Instead of

```
for i in range(len(total_val_count)):
    print(total_val_count.iloc[i])
```

you could use

```
for value in total_val_count.values:
    print(value)
```

This is more readable, and allows you to access the desired value as a variable, `value`, instead of the more cumbersome `total_val_count.iloc[i]`.

Here is an example which shows how to iterate over the values, the keys, both the keys and values:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 2, 2])
total_val_count = s.value_counts()

print(total_val_count)
# 2    3
# 3    1
# 1    1
# dtype: int64

for value in total_val_count.values:
    print(value)
    # 3
    # 1
    # 1

for key in total_val_count.keys():
    print(key)
    # 2
    # 3
    # 1

for key, value in total_val_count.iteritems():
    print(key, value)
    # (2, 3)
    # (3, 1)
    # (1, 1)

for i in range(len(total_val_count)):
    print(total_val_count.iloc[i])
    # 3
    # 1
    # 1
```